# error: conditional compilation flags must be valid Swift identifiers (rather than 'DEBUG”')

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode9

I'm trying to build my project with Xcode 9 beta 6 (9M214v). Also, I'm using CocoaPods. I've converted to Swift 4 and updated my project settings, but I keep getting this error.

Things I've tried so far:

- Clean project and build folder
- Deleting / re-adding pods
- Restart Xcode
- Remove `Active Compilation Conditions` flags

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Error message:

```
<unknown>:0: error: conditional compilation flags must be valid Swift identifiers (rather than 'DEBUG”')
Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Podfile

```
target 'iOS Application' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'SwiftLint'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

Comment: Do you get this error when creating the pods or when trying to build your project? Did you actually check your project settings if the "DEBUG" flag is set or not?

Comment: @DávidPásztor When I try to build the project. For my project, the flag is not set, for the Pods project, it is. If I delete it there too, it still doesn't build. However, my Travis build is passing, so it must be something wrong locally

Comment: `(rather than 'DEBUG”')` Strangely there is an extra double quote in the definition of `DEBUG"` vs `DEBUG`.

Comment: @Larme I saw that too, but all of the flags are set correctly in Xcode without the ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error! In my `iOS Application` target's Build Settings, at `Swift Compiler - Custom Flags > Other Swift Flags`. There was a ”, instead of " at the end of the flag. I have no idea how this happened, but the quotation mark caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

I find when you modify your "x-Code" setting for custom flags "Debug" to delete "-D",and then replace your swift language version to "Swift 4.0" ,It will fix your problem! Hoping help you...